# raw frames windows phone 8.1

Tags: camera, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I need to get raw frames from the Camera in YUV/YCbCr format on windows phone 8.1 (**without Silverlight**), I don't see any example on internet, is it possible using MediaCapture or CameraPreviewImageSource (Nokia SDK) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to process raw video frames on Windows Phone 8.1 is to write a custom [MFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703138(v=vs.85).aspx) plug-in and then add it to the [MediaCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.aspx) object via [AddEffectAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211961.aspx). The MFT acts as a DSP filter between the decoder and the XAML rich compositor.

You can choose the color space that you want to support in your MFT and Media Foundation will automatically insert color space converters for you. Keep in mind that the color spaces available on the Phone are limited. That said, [NV12](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd206750(v=vs.85).aspx) is the standard color space for most video devices and is considered a 4:2:0 YUV color space.

While this sounds simple in theory it can be quite complex in practice. MFTs must be writing in C++ / MoCom. Writing an MFT does require rather deep knowledge of C++ and COM. I don't want to scare you away from giving it a try but it does have a learning curve.

Here is a sample for Windows Store that shows you how to create a MFT plug-in and add it to the MediaCapture object. Unfortunately for whatever reason this sample did not get converted to a Universal app. However, it should be easy to do the conversion. Since this is such a seminal sample I will request that we publish it as a universal app.

[Media capture using capture device sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622)

I hope this helps,

James

Comment: Thank you for your help James. I saw that earlier but I was expected to not use it. Also I was wondering is this example a good example ? Do you think I can use the "GrayScale" code provided in this example ? Basically if I'm not wrong, the camera capture raw frame, compressed those frames and then with a MFT I will uncompressed them to have those raw frame ? Isn't it too much use of the phone's cpu ?

Comment: Hello Sebastien, The "GrayScale" MFT is a great place to start and should be very easy to port it to your Windows Phone Runtime app. I've worked with several deverlopers that have done it successfully.

Comment: When you add your MFT via "AddEffectAsync" it is added before the encoder so you will get "raw" uncompressed frames.

Comment: great ! thank you very much for your help ! One more question. How many frames should I be able to capture per second ? Without the help of lowlagphotoCapture or VariablePhotoSequence, those are not supported on my phone, even it's a nokia Icon pretty new.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. On most devices the framerate is locked at 60 fps. Are you asking how many photos you can take per second?

Comment: yes I am. But Can I take 60 frame per second without using VariablePhotoSequenceController class : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.devices.core.variablephotosequencecontroller.aspx , which is not supported on my device ?