# Windows Phone 8 saving video stream to file after event trigger

Tags: windows-phone-8, video

I'm looking for some suggestions or pointers on where to look or how to get started with a project for Windows Phone 8.1.  The idea is pretty simple in my mind.  I want to constantly record video to a memory stream only keeping say the last five seconds, then an event will trigger saving the video steam to a file on to the phone.

I was originally thinking I could save raw frames to a ring buffer and define the size based on the raw frame size * sample rate.  Now I realize that might not work because the video provided by the MediaCapture class will be encoded.  Digging on stackoverflow, I came across the idea of using [MFTs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785463/raw-frames-windows-phone-8-1) but it sounds a lot more complicated than I originally had in mind.

Looking around the Development Reference material on MSDN, I'm guessing the [MediaCapture class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture) will be my friend.  Can I somehow define a fixed size stream for use with MediaCapture.StartRecordToStreamAsync then on my event connect it to MediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync?  Or perhaps there might be a more appropriate way to do this that I should investigate?